# didSelectRowAtIndexPath in editing mode to update data

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i try to modify my didSelectRowAtIndexPath Method to use my AddView also for editing (only with filled textfields). But it is not working! I just enter edit mode, check if(self.editing) and do something like:

```
   if (self.editing) {
        AddViewController *viewController = [[AddViewController alloc] 
                                             initWithNibName:@"AddView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    //get selected Object  
    User *userEdit = [[User alloc] init];
    userEdit = [self.users objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    viewController.user = userEdit;
    [viewController setEditUser];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    [viewController release];
    //deselect Row after navigate back
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

What am I doing wrong? I also try to send the User object like [viewController setEditUser:editUser] but this is also not working, so i tried it with init.

My setEditUser Method looks like (in the view)

```
- (void)setEditUser{
self.userTitle.text = self.user.title; //this is not working!!! ?????
NSLog(@"blub %@", self.user.title); //this is working!!!!
```

}

Thanks for your Help

Comment: First, `userEdit = [[User alloc] init];` is wrong and creates a memory leak. Just remove it. Second, you are not showing us the relevant code. What are we to deduct from the fact that `self.user.servertitle` apparently contains the string you expect and `self.user.title` might not? We know nothing about these objects and how you create them.

Comment: sorry misstyping, should be in both cases user.title

I have following params in my view:
@synthesize user, userTitle;

and in my header file
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *userTitle;
and
User *user;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if i do the textfield value setting at

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
self.userTitle.text = self.user.title;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you are asking, but maybe you should have a look at

`@property(nonatomic) BOOL allowsSelectionDuringEditing`

Discussion

If the value of this property is YES , users can select rows during editing. The default value is NO. If you want to restrict selection of cells regardless of mode, use allowsSelection.

on the UITableView documentation.

Comment: thanks, im able to do editing :) But im not able to send data to my view (textfields are not displaying the values, NSLog does)